# the maximum amount of $m\sin{kx} + n\cos{px}$

Tags: trigonometry

for all real numbers x, find the maximum amount of $$m\sin{kx} + n\cos{px}$$
I know that we could solve this problem by using differential calculus:
$$ f(x) = m\sin{kx} + n\cos{px} \therefore f^\prime(x) = mk\cos(kx) - np\sin(px) $$
the we have:
$$ \frac{mk}{np}\cos(kx) = \sin(px) \therefore x = \frac{1}{p}\arcsin(\frac{mk}{np}\cos(kx))$$
but this is not what I am looking for and I don't know how to solve it. please help.

Comment: Hint: in this case, x is fixed, but m and n are changing. Also, should we assume m and n are integers?

Comment: no in this case x is not fixed we need to maximize the function f(x). the question is not asking for which m,n,k,p the function is maximized.